# NullPointerException when I'm executing jestClient to index into Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I've been struggling with NullPointerException when I'm executing jestClient to index into Elasticsearch for two days.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1770)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:943)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:936)
at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:345)
at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.write(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:88)
at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.write(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:40)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:125)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:243)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ObjectTypeAdapter.write(ObjectTypeAdapter.java:107)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:97)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:208)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:669)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:648)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:603)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:583)
at io.searchbox.action.AbstractAction.getData(AbstractAction.java:167)
at io.searchbox.core.Bulk.getData(Bulk.java:102)
at io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient.prepareRequest(JestHttpClient.java:115)
at io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient.execute(JestHttpClient.java:64)
at io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient.execute(JestHttpClient.java:60)
at com.example.testcb.databus.RealTimeDataSink.saveToElasticSearch(RealTimeDataSink.java:154)
at com.example.testcb.databus.RealTimeDataSink.productionMessageSink(RealTimeDataSink.java:64)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:180)
at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:112)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(StreamListenerMessageHandler.java:48)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.DispatchingStreamListenerMessageHandler$ConditionalStreamListenerHandler.handleMessage(DispatchingStreamListenerMessageHandler.java:122)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.DispatchingStreamListenerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(DispatchingStreamListenerMessageHandler.java:75)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:425)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:375)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:360)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:271)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:188)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.FixedSubscriberChannel.send(FixedSubscriberChannel.java:70)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.FixedSubscriberChannel.send(FixedSubscriberChannel.java:64)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:188)
at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.access$000(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:54)
at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:288)
at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:279)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter$1.doWithRetry(RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter.java:79)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter$1.doWithRetry(RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter.java:73)
at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:287)
at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:180)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter.java:73)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter.java:39)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:794)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:738)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.access$2200(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:245)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer$ListenerInvoker.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1031)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Let me add my code to understand the situation.

```
public void saveToElasticSearch(String type, JSONArray outputs) throws Exception{

    if (outputs != null) {

        boolean indexExists = jestClient.execute(new IndicesExists.Builder(INDEX_NAME).build()).isSucceeded();

        try {
            Bulk.Builder bulkIndexBuilder = new Bulk.Builder();

            for(Object object : outputs) {
                bulkIndexBuilder.addAction(new Index.Builder(object).index(INDEX_NAME).type(type).build());
                System.out.println(object);
            }
            jestClient.execute(bulkIndexBuilder.build());

        } catch(NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

To be honest, I have no idea how to figure this out. Here are objects printed in a code.

```
{"timeStamp":1509496260000,"data":[com.example.testcb.domain.RealTimeProduction@1ab971fb],"equipment":"LA-081","unitTime":Wed Nov 01 09:31:00 KST 2017}
{"timeStamp":1509496320000,"data":[com.example.testcb.domain.RealTimeProduction@8e0a2c3],"equipment":"LA-081","unitTime":Wed Nov 01 09:32:00 KST 2017}
{"timeStamp":1509496200000,"data":[com.example.testcb.domain.RealTimeProduction@426b9507],"equipment":"LA-091","unitTime":Wed Nov 01 09:30:00 KST 2017}
```

Maybe I can be related to an object which has java address above? Any idea of this?

Comment: Have you checked the Elastic discussion forums? Have you posted your question there already? https://discuss.elastic.co/

Comment: It seems that the GSON serialization seeks to parse some date field which is null. Are you sure all your documents/objects have non-null date fields (probably in RealTimeProduction objects)

Comment: do you get NPE always or its on some specific data ?

Comment: To get this error, it means Gson has sent a `null` `java.util.Date` object  to java Date formatter. What Gson version is used here ? Is there no patch update that can be applied ?

Answer (score 3):

As the stack trace you provided in the question indicates, the error is related to the fact that the Gson library, used internally by Jest for JSON processing, is not handling appropriately `null` values when processing some date values contained in your data.

The problem was reported in [this](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1120) and especially [this other](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1096) Github issues, and fixed in Gson [`2.8.2`](https://github.com/google/gson/compare/gson-parent-2.8.1...gson-parent-2.8.2).

The aforementioned issues indicate that everything should work properly with Gson 2.8.0, the version bounded with Jest, but please, in any case, due to the fact that AFAIK is not possible to define your own JSON (de)serializers or tweak the Gson existing ones when configuring Jest, try providing a version of Gson in which the problem is solved in your Maven or Gradle as a first level dependency, forcing your project to use it. For example:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks - my team confirmed the Gson / Jest problem, but didn't realize we could specify the version of this dependency in Maven until your answer. This helped us solve our problem.

Comment: You are welcome. That is nice Brian, I am happy to hear that you were able to solve the problem.